# Is it worth using Backbone on a site that isn't totally RESTful?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got a site which isn't REST based and I'm auditing my front-end and planning on re-writing it. I enjoy using Backbone, but not taking full advantage of Backbone (since my site isn't a single page app and I'm not necessarily consuming or bootstrapping any data on page load with `fetch` or updating with `sync`.

Does it make sense to keep Backbone around or should I be looking elsewhere? Or on top of that, should I make my back-end more RESTful?

Comment: What do you mainly use Backbone for? If you are willing to learn a new framework (with a small up-front time investment but huge productivity boost down the road), you should check out React or Angular which will give you a lot more than Backbone does.

Comment: Yes of course, then you can make it RESTful!

Answer (score 1):

I still like using it for non-REST projects because it helps me organize my code.

If your codebase is easier to understand and easier to maintain when you use Backbone than when you don't, there's no shame in using it. Same goes for any of the other frameworks out there.